# How do you split multiple polylines by a field name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, arcgis-10.4

I used the point to line tool in order to create lines going from one point to another. Each line essentially represents the route taken by an individual. How would I be able to separate the lines by the individuals name or objectid?

[image]

Each row has an independent line associated with it and I would like to take the shapefile shown in the screenshot and split it into multiple shapefiles depending on the name.

Comment: By separate do you mean multipart to single part?

Comment: Can you please confirm that these are *multipart* polylines rather than must multiple polyline features?  A multipart polyline has one record made up of different spatial parts (lines with gaps), however what you have shown in your screenshot is multiple records.

Comment: I am unsure of what you would actually call it I guess. Each row has an independent line associated with it and I would like to take the shapefile shown in the screenshot and split it into multiple shapefiles depending on the name. hopefully this explanation helps a little bit more.

Comment: @Devin Please always [edit] your question to include additional information or clarification, rather than adding as comments

Comment: @Devin Are the values in `Name` unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way (without using Python) would be to select your line in the table (interactively or with SQL query) and save the selection as new shapefile. This is ok if you don't have too many individual lines you want to create; If you do,USGS has a nice plugg-in for this purpose : https://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html

or use `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management` in a loop.